# How to set size of the seekbar thumb in xml in android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how I can set the size (height, width) of the thumb in seekbar. I googled and found this to be done only through code. But I want this to set in xml only.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around for exactly what you need, you just need to use an image and place it in your xml at `android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_slider"` 
you can use this thumb as per your choice .
It doesn't exaclty answer your question but you can do it as a workaround, a thinner drawable would reduce the Thumb size ofcourse.